# MVVM in WPF and many refresh actions interlinked

Tags: wpf, model-view-controller, mvvm

We maintain a large WPF MVVM application and I notice that the databindings (properties and commands) result in large and therefore obscure stacktraces.

E.g. I close a certain view `A` and I observe that a certain method to load view `A` is called 2 times in a row.

View `<-->`  ViewModel `<-->` Data Model

What I miss is a controller in between that determines what views and which parts of views need an update.

View `<-->`  Controller `<-->` ViewModel `<-->` Data Model

In WPF-MVVM the controller part is the data-binding, that I would like to manage better.
Who has a nice idea + example code how to improve this in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem cannot be solved by WPF, but must be tackled by [a better architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316931/is-there-a-good-formal-pattern-to-manage-state-in-mvvm).

A high level "master viewmodel" could act as a controller or mediator that orchestrates the refresh actions, especially their order.

I cannot say whether perhaps [redux.NET](https://github.com/GuillaumeSalles/redux.NET) also helps.